# Change the alpha value of a hex integer on the fly

Tags: java, android

I've got this loop that is run thousands of times (so needs to be efficient). It changes the value of the bitmap pixel.

I want to be able to run thought the loop and "switch" a certain group of pixels to alpha and then switch them back at a later point.

My question is.
How do I switch the values? So say 0xFFCC1BE0 becomes 0x00CC1BE0 and then if I want to switch back to 0xFFCC1BE0 I simply take the 00 and turn it too FF.

I can't make two bitmaps as I run out of memory :-(

Anyhow here's what I've got so far:

```
private void setTransparencyOnLightMap(float WidthPercentage, float LeftPosition)
{
    int blankPixel = 0x00000000;
    int savedPixel = 0x00000000;
    int desiredAlpha = 200; //Can also be 0x00
    //Find away of turning alhpa off and on.

    for(int BMx = 0; BMx < mLightMap.getWidth(); BMx++)
    {
        for(int BMy = 0; BMy < mLightMap.getHeight(); BMy++)
        {
            if(mLightMap.getPixel(BMx, BMy) != blankPixel) //Make sure don't overwrite blank transparent pixels.
            {
                savedPixel = mLightMap.getPixel(BMx,BMy);
                savedPixel = savedPixel | (desiredAlpha << 24);

                mLightMap.setPixel(BMx, BMy, savedPixel);
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could switch the alpha of a pixel like so:

```
savedPixel = savedPixel & 0x00FFFFFF;
savedPixel = savedPixel | (desiredAlpha << 24);
```

The first line zeros out the 8 most significant bits of savedPixel (these are the bits where the alpha is held).  The second line sets the 8 most significant bits of savedPixel to desiredAlpha.  Note that desiredAlpha must be between 0 and 255 (These are the ints that can be stored in 8 bits).

Note that this uses bitwise operators, (&, |, <<) which are very efficient.

Comment: That should be `<< 24`, not 23. See [this Python code](http://codepad.org/2s15Mqb6).

Comment: This is the first time I've come across bitwise operators, just taking sometime to understand them.

So I can switch the old colour back on? (without any storage correct?)

Comment: No you would have to store your old alpha.  You cannot just switch it back as the alpha could be anything before you switch it. The alpha is only 2 bytes however.  If you wanted to switch the alpha back, you would do the same as above replacing "desiredAlpha" with your old alpha value.

Comment: But I don't have the old value, so there's no way of just turning off the first 2 bits the turning them back on again?

Comment: If the old value is constant, then you could do that.  Otherwise, I recommend storing your old values in an array of some sort.

Comment: How would I do this say: "0x00" + Old value half, then when I want it back on "0xFF" + old value half (unchanged). Problem is I only know how todo it with string and it's slow.

Comment: Simply use the answer I posted.  For 0x00 + Old value half, just set desiredAlpha to 0x00.  (The same is true for 0xFF).  To see which value you needed (0x00 or 0xFF), just use and if statement to check the value of the alpha.

Comment: I used your answer but the pixels goes really bright when I turn the alpha back off.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me, to reduce memory use, you can just save the original Alpha value of each pixel rather than the whole ARGB value - to do this use a byte array which will be 1/4 the size of the original bitmap. Also use a bit-mask for the new Alpha so you can use bitwise AND (`&`) as described by Tristan Hull...

```
byte[] savedAlphaArray = new byte[mLightMap.getWidth(), mLightMap.getHeight()];
int desiredAlphaMask = 0x00FFFFFF;
int pixel;
```

Then to save the Alpha values and apply the bit-mask do the following...

```
for (int i = 0; i < mLightMap.getWidth(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < mLightMap.getHeight(); j++) {
        pixel = mLightMap.getPixel(i, j);
        savedAlphaArray[i, j] = (pixel & 0xFF000000) >> 24;
        mLightMap.setPixel(i, j, desiredAlphaMask & pixel);
    }
}
```

To 'switch' back do the following...

```
for (int i = 0; i < mLightMap.getWidth(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < mLightMap.getHeight(); j++) {
        pixel = mLightMap.getPixel(i, j);
        mLightMap.setPixel(i, j, savedAlphaArray[i, j] << 24 & pixel);
    }
}
```

Comment: Will this work well with a png that already has alpha values in some parts?

Comment: @AbakizMyth : To be honest I really don't know. I've never tried the code I posted and was only working on what the question was asking for. Simply saving the original Alpha then setting it with the bit-mask and then alternative code to restore the original Alpha. It's basically just Hex logic.